Download a file with Flask
I'm trying to download an Excel file with Flask, but the browser doesn't initiate any download. Here's the function that should perform the download:
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    # Executed when Export button is clicked
    if request.method == 'POST':
        parsed_input = parse_input_data(request.get_json())
        export_df = export_rules(parsed_input)
        session['export_completed'] = True
        # Write DataFrame to BytesIO object
        excel_buffer = BytesIO()
        export_df.to_excel(excel_buffer, index=False)
        excel_buffer.seek(0)
        # Send BytesIO object as a file attachment
        return send_file(excel_buffer,
                         as_attachment=True,
                         download_name='rules.xlsx',
                         mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    return render_template('home.html',
                           netact_release_options = retrive_releases(),
                           netact_size_options = [],
                           ne_roles_options = [])

I've checked the response headers, and they should be correct:
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.xlsx
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Content-Length: 6093
Cache-Control: no-cache

I also tried changing the browser, changing the network, and clearing the browser cache, but I didn't solve the problem.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

you can try to use mimetype="application/octet-stream" to force browser to download it instead of displaying.

Since you are not writing to a file but a memory buffer have a look at this

I solve the problem by creating an endpoint to download the file (using send_file function), and then call it from the the client side with AJAX request.
